# Using method only a single element

Tags: jquery

I have this test page:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<h1>test1</h1>
<h1>test2</h1>
<h1>test3</h1>
```

I can hide all elements using `$('h1').hide()`, but for what reason I can not only hide the second element, using `$('h1')[1].hide()`? How can I do this?

Using `$('h1')[1].hide()` I get the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[1].hide is not a function
    at <anonymous>:2:12
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)
```

Comment: $('h1').eq(1).hide()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.eq()` function in jQuery instead of the [1] directly.

https://api.jquery.com/eq/

So, you'd do something like this `$('h1').eq(1).hide();`

Or you can use the `:eq()` sub-selector

https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

So, you'd do something like this `$('h1:eq(1)').hide();`

Comment: Becuase the return value of $(selector) is a jQuery object, not a pure javascript array of items.  In this case it is a jQuery object that contains a list of items that mach the selector, so you'd have to use a jQuery function access one single item from the list.

Answer (score 2):

You should use another jQuery selector for this - its the :nth-child()-selector (see docs: https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/). In your example this can be used like the following:

```
jQuery('h1:nth-child(2)').hide();
```